# How to Set Custom Price in virtuemart

Tags: php, e-commerce, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I managed in VM 1.xxx to create a custom calculation and pass results on to the cart (see: http://carmatsuk.ingitglobal.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=1232&virtuemart_category_id=469).

Can anyone point me to what is the route for the addtocart part.

How can I add my own price to the cart.I only want that my custom price should be added to cart not the actual price of product.

Thanks heaps in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Custom field - Price per input , and you set price 1$ and with javascript write in this field as much letters as much correction of price you need : 
exmp. basic price 100$ , calculation price 254$ -> difference 154$ you write 154 letters in custom price input text and you have your final price 254$ in your basket.